# Can WiX act much like a script? Perhaps there is an alternative

Tags: powershell, wix, windows-installer, nsis

I am looking for a solution to create an installer that will have to be able to do things like:

- *before building installer exe* Gather resources (updates) from several servers (using FTP, SVN and HTTP)
- Be compiled (automatically) with updated version (so that it can be done using a shortcut)

After the installer is built, it is copied on a machine with no internet connection and should be able to:

- Update Oracle database to certain version (using pl/sql files that were downloaded when installer was fetching resources
- Update software (replace files) basing on version number - the information could be stored in the registry
- Update software by replacing strings in specific files (.ini)
- Install windows' services and roles
- Work with IIS (hence adding application pools etc)
- Work with certificate store (installing CA's etc)

Basically many of those things above (except app/oracle updater) can be done using cmd.exe/PowerShell and checking return codes.

Until now I was using NSIS for simplier tasks and yes, the code looked long but conditional building and loops were quite obvious.

I read about WiX where people claimed it to be difficult to learn but you benefit in the future. Why? Because of the auto-repair/uninstall function?

I was wondering how easy it is to write sort of programming-alike code in XML (functions, loops, conditions).

Comment: WiX is hard to learn because MSI is hard to learn.  WiX is just an abstraction on top of MSI to author MSI.  MSI is hard to learn because there are very few people to teach it, the written resources are cryptic and the model is very different then what most developers are used to.

Comment: BTW, it is possible to remove certain standard actions from an MSI so that it never registers itself with the system. In that sense it can be used as a sophisticated script.   Microsoft uses this technique for it's "Mr FixIt" packages.

Answer (score 3):

Your first set of bullets are not the function of an installer, it's a function of your build automation / continuous integration system.

Your second set of bullets are all implemented by WiX except for Oracle.  MSSQL only is natively supported.

WiX is a tool to author Windows Installer (MSI) databases. It's important to understand that MSI is *NOT* a scripting language.  It is not an imperative (procedural or OO ) programming model, it is a declarative programing model.

MSI abstracts how to do something from what to do.  Table data (WiX elements and attributes) describes what needs to be done and MSI standard actions and WiX built-in custom actions  implement the how to do it.   MSI at install time evaluates table data and generates a script to install, uninstall, rollback and commit installation changes inside of an installation transaction.

The reason this is important is that once you understand the patterns (a tough hill to climb I'll admit)  your installers are much simpler, robust and scalable. I've written tomes of installers using scripting languages in the past and my productivity and reliability is much better using MSI.

Answer (score 1):

For my opinion it does'nt matter which bigger installer solution you use, your requirements need an installer which could be customized via script. So it's not easier or more difficult to learn this or that scripting language.

WiX could all these things, what you wanted to do. It has this oportunities:
- conditional build
- custom scripting
- uses custom parameters
- can be automated via console called build

An alternative could be InnoSetup which does'nt cost anything and can effort all things above too. Link: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

I can't say whether both of the systems support MAC or other OS than windows.

It really doesn't matter which installer you choose, with your requirements no installer could do the installation process without customization. And you have to learn the dependent scripting language.

Hope my answer helps?!